# ContentFlow: how to not scale the pictures?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, coverflow

I am using the excellent jQuery coverflow plugin [ContentFlow](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow) but I have a problem with it.

The picture at the center is always scaled too much, which makes it blurry. After countless tries, I still cannot see where the problem comes from.

Here are the relevant config options:

```
// overall scale factor of content    
scaleFactor: 1.0,

// scale factor of landscape images ('max' := height= maxItemHeight)    
scaleFactorLandscape: "max",     

// scale factor of portraoit and square images ('max' := width = item width)    
scaleFactorPortrait: "max",
```

I found that by setting the `scaleFactor` around 0.84, the image shown in the flow is the same size as the original one, but still blurry. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that by setting the height to the exact height of the picture, the problem is solved.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on how you did that? I'm having the same problem... Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Ben sorry I lost the access to my account and was never notified of your question. If you still need it, here is the answer: you need to set the `maxItemHeight`parameter to the height of your images, for example: `maxItemHeight: 150`